# Memory exceeded when write excel file using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

My VPS has 8GB memory

When I try to write 4000 Rows and 62 Columns. 1 column has an image (PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing)

After writing some data OS has kill background script because VPS has not had more memory.

I'm using PHPExcel version 1.7.8

I have writing excel file in each loop.

Image write sample code

```
$gdImage = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($proof_photo_1));
if ($gdImage) {
    $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
    $objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
    $objDrawing->setCoordinates("BA" . $i);
    $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
    $objDrawing->setHeight(150);
    $width = $objDrawing->getWidth() * 0.143;
    $height = $objDrawing->getHeight() * 0.75;
    if ($rowDim->getRowHeight() < $height) {
        $rowDim->setRowHeight($height);
    }
    $colDimSh = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension("BA");
    $colDimSh->setAutoSize(false);
    $colDim = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension("BA");
    if ($colDim->getWidth() < $width) {
        $colDim->setWidth($width);
    }
    unset($objDrawing);
} else {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("BA" . $i, "-");
}
```

I have tried many things to save memory

```
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
$cacheSettings = array('memoryCacheSize' => '100MB');
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod,$cacheSettings);
```

In side each loop

```
if($i % 100 == 0){
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save($csvPath);
    $objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();
    unset($objWriter);
    unset($objPHPExcel);
    chmod($csvPath, 0777);

    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($csvPath);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
}
```

Above take much time for write excel file and sometimes file reset from begaing.

Comment: Have you tried using setCellValueExplicit?

Comment: The amount of RAM your VPS has may not be important. The question is, how is PHP configured. You may want to increase memory limit for PHP. You didn't provided error message, so it's hard to tell if your configuration is reasonable.

Comment: @MichaelH Would you please tell me how this is used in my case?

Comment: @JakubMatczak I have increase memory limit to -1 that's why script exceeded VPS memory other wise PHP thorow memory limit error

Comment: $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit("BA" . $i, "-");

Comment: @DipeshShihora I think you would because it avoids additional method calls and logic that setCellValue incurs.  Are you fine when you do not write the image to the spreadsheet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182271/discussion-between-dipesh-shihora-and-michael-h).